# analyzing patterns in multiple crash dumps

Tags: pattern-matching, stack-trace

I see a lot of crash dumps from an application that I maintain. The facility I work at has
hundreds of users who use this tool, all around the world, hence the high number of crash dumps. These dumps have a signature that looks like:

```
QObject::event(QEvent*)
QidleTimer::event(QEvent*)
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*)
QmayaApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*)
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*)
g_main_context_dispatch
g_main_context_iteration
QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
QCoreApplication::exec()
__libc_start_main
```

The class names and signatures are diverse (some have been redacted). What I would like to do is write a tool that analyzes these traces for patterns among the crashes. I was wondering, if you knew of any techniques I could use to analyze input like this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Part 3 of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0955832802) has a section on *Crash Dump Analysis Patterns*, but they're oriented towards Windows OS. The author also has a [blog with an analysis patterns tag](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/category/crash-dump-patterns/). This is not an endorsement of the book (I don't own it).